# How can I concatenate 2 query sets in django to write in xlwt Excel file?

Tags: django, django-queryset, xlwt

I have 2 models class, I have to concatenate these query set objects and write one Excel file. How can I do it?

I use this code but it doesn't work, it writes the second query set data under another types of objects. Like this :[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NHaj.png) [image of what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvQLz.png)

```
  def export_excel(request):

     response =HttpResponse(content_type = 'application/ms-excel')
     response['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="persondatas.xls"' 
     wb = xlwt.Workbook(encoding='utf-8')
     ws = wb.add_sheet('AllinOne')
     row_num = 0
     font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
     font_style.font.bold = True


     columns = ['name', 'fulname', 'id', 'gender', 'country', 'birthdate', 'birthpace', 
               'departament', 'feature']
     for col_num in range(len(columns)):
           ws.write(row_num, col_num, columns[col_num], font_style)

     font_style = xlwt.XFStyle()
     rows =Person.objects.values_list('name', 'lastname', 'selfid', 'gender', 'country', 
              'dateofbirth', 'placeofbirth')
     jobs = Enrollment.objects.values_list('departament', 'feature')
     querysets = [rows, jobs]
     rows = list(chain(*querysets))
    
     for row in rows: 
        row_num+=1
        for col_num in range(len(row)):
         ws.write(row_num, col_num, str(row[col_num]), font_style)


    wb.save(response)
```

Comment: What is it that isn't working here?

Comment: It writes second list objects under another columns

Comment: Wel, yes, that's what you've told it to do by concatenating them all as a list of rows. What do you _actually_ want to do then? 2 different tabs within the same excel file maybe? Also, your sheet is called "AllinOne", which kind of indicates you want them all in the same sheet?

Comment: so, i wanna  distinguish these list elements, but when i use this i get different result

Comment: I'm sorry, could you add some clarification in your question about actual and expected output please. I can't tell what you mean by "distinguish these list elements" and "different result".

Comment: up I have added images as a question description, u can see and i think u will understand what i mean